# Escape brackets in python regex

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-re

I want to search a substring from a string log like below, `re.escape` seems not working in my case, I would like some advises.

```
log = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx found targets:['123-321', '123-456'] asdasdasjdlajdlkajdlsk"

node_ids = ['123-321', '123-456']
node_ids = re.escape(str(node_ids))
substr = = f"targets: {node_ids}"
print(node_ids)
print(re.findall(substr, log))
```

Output

```
targets: \[\'123\-321\'\,\ \'123\-456\'\]
[]
```

Comment: `log` doesn't contain `targets: ` with a space.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here

```
substr = f"targets: {node_ids}"
```

This means that the string must contain  `targets:` followed by a ***Space***, which does not exist in `log`.

```
>>> import re
>>> log = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx found targets:['123-321', '123-456'] asdasdasjdlajdlkajdlsk"
>>> node_ids = ['123-321', '123-456']
>>> node_ids = re.escape(str(node_ids))
>>> substr = f"targets:{node_ids}"
>>> print(re.findall(substr, log))
["targets:['123-321', '123-456']"]
```